# How to embed Dask's dashboard plots directly into JupyterLab panes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I am new to dask,

Can anyone help me how to embed Dask's dashboard plots,Dask Graph directly into JupyterLab panes. without

`Dask JupyterLab Extension` ??

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using the Dask JupyterLab extension.

If you want to make it yourself then you will need to make new iframes in JLab panes, and use the `/individual-*` pages hosted by the Dask scheduler dashboard.